# Coercing a string to an integer in GolfScript

Tags: tips, golfscript

**GolfScript** automatically coerces values, according to the following ‘priority’ sequence:

> integer → array → string → block

(listed from lowest to highest.)

This means that `"1"7+` leaves the string `"17"` on the stack (and not `8`), because strings have a higher priority than integers.

[*To those GolfScript veterans – apologies for insulting your respective intelligences.*]

How would it be possible to do this the other way? That is, to **coerce a string into an integer**?

Comment: `name:~ args:1 functions:bitwise not, dump, eval`

Comment: [This](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IjEifjcr&input=) gives `8`.

Comment: @LeakyNun; Nice! Do you want to want to put this in an answer? I'd certainly accept it.

Comment: @closevoter [Questions asking tips about golfing code are on-topic.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/53917)

Comment: @downvoter; could you please leave a comment explaining why you have downvoted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an operator `~` in golfscript, which does the following: `bitwise not, dump, eval`.

Therefore, `"1"` will give the string `"1"` while `"1"~` will evaluate that string (into the integer `1`).

Then, all you need to do is `"1"~7+`.

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IjEifjcr&input=)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is an `eval` of golfscript code, meaning e.g. `"1.0"~` does something unexpected.