# PowerShell: test connection in as few characters as possible

Tags: code-golf, tips, powershell

I need this down to as few characters as possible.  I would use Test-NetConnection but I need PSv2 compatability.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$socket = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$socket.Connect("192.168.5.5",445)
$socket.Connected
```

As a note I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
(new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("192.168.5.5",445).Connected
```

Comment: My code does work.  I am proposing the challenge of "make it as few characters as possible".  I fail to see how this is considered "off topic" when one of the topics is "programming challenges".  Please explain....

Comment: @apsillers This is a perfectly on-topic question; we've accepted many "how can I make my code shorter" questions in the past: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91350/), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91310/), [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90667/), [4](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90531/), [5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85525/), [6](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80073/), [7](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77793/), [8](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71613/), etc.

Comment: This would be better suited for [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) or something. IMO, it doesn't warrant its own question on the main site.

Comment: @NickClifford This type of question, while uncommon, [is absolutely on topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1724/8478).

Comment: @NickClifford Viewed as a narrowly-applied `[tips]` question, rather than as a challenge, this is indeed on topic. (I say this as someone who originally voted to close the question.)

Comment: @apsillers Ah, I see.

Comment: OP, just to explain the contention here, the site accepts two types of posts: "challenges" to achieve some general goal ("Given a number as input, compute the lowest prime number higher than the input number" as one simple example) and "tips" which ask for help golfing in a particular language. "Tips" posts are comparatively rare, and are largely language-specific compendiums of knowledge (e.g., [Tips for golfing in Windows PowerShell](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191/7796). However, tips-posts asking to golf a particular problem are allowed, but fairly uncommon, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no default alias for `New-Object`, and no type accelerator for `Net.Sockets.TcpClient`, so they can't be any shorter. You can merge the constructor and connect code into one line:

```
(New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient -A 192.168.5.5,445)
```

But if it can't connect, it now throws an exception, which you can't silence with -ErrorAction. So handling that ends up being 70 characters, only 8 shorter than your original after shrinking the variable name:

```
!!$(try{(new-object net.sockets.tcpclient -A 192.168.5.5,445)}catch{})
```

`!!` forcing the result to a bool.

Comment: My final solution ended up taking parts from both of your answers:
`While(!!(New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient (192.168.5.5,445))){}`
Thank you both for your input!  I gave the answer to TesselatingHeckler's because I was impressed at the way he returned a bool value in only two characters.  Quite impressive!

Answer (score 6):

#### PowerShell v2+, 63 bytes

You can use a [different constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.80).aspx) to create the object and connect in one go.

```
(new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient('192.168.5.5',445)).Connected
```

I've verified this works in v2 on my Windows 8.1 machine. That constructor is supported by .NET 2.0, so this should be v2 compatible.

Comment: Can replace `'192.168.5.5'` with `3232236805`

Comment: @ceilingcat Can you explain that?

Comment: @MichaelTimmerman The integer 3232236805 is equal to 192*256^3 + 168*256^2 + 5*256 + 5, the native format that the TCP stack uses internally.

Comment: @ceilingcat Just tested this by pinging 192.168.1.1.  I would have never in a million years guessed that this would work lol.  I'll be sure to remember this.  Thank you for explaining :)